# Sqlite3 about 6X slower than grep

Tags: python, bash, sqlite, grep

I have a table with 188 Million Lines and a text file with 188 Million Lines as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE trigram (count integer, A text, B text, C text)
time echo 'select * from trigram where C="mailman";'|sqlite3 3g.db
18.419 seconds.
time grep 'mailman$' N-Grams/3g
3.137 seconds
```

or a more complicated query like

```
time grep 'the [^ ]* mailman$' N-Grams/3g 
2.879 seconds
time echo 'select * from trigram where A="the" and C="mailman";'|sqlite3 3g.db
15.839 seconds
```

Is there any way I can speed `sqlite3` up?

Comment: give berkleydb a try. its supposed to be faster than sqlite, and aimed at similar workflows.

Comment: What versions, operating systems, configurations, etc...?

Comment: Latest Linux Ubuntu and grep sqlite3, but Mr. Larry Lustig's answer executed in 0.002s!

Answer (score 7):

Create an index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trigram_col_c ON trigram(C);
```

and then try again.

You can get more speed on the second query with a covering index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trigram_col_c ON trigram(C, A);
```

or

```
CREATE INDEX idx_trigram_col_c ON trigram(A, C);
```

(if the columns have different distributions put the one with more values first).

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much! 0.002 seconds!